# SQL - Triple nested while insert

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-insert

I have this code for insert rows to table. I have three while nesthed themself, but this code give me

```
error #1064 - bad syntax  close

    BEGIN
            WHILE p <= 5
            BEGIN
                WHILE ra <= 40
            ' on line 7.
```

What is wrong with this code?

```
 DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE proc()
BEGIN
    DECLARE r int DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE p int DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE ra int DEFAULT 1;
    WHILE r <= 8 DO

        WHILE p <= 5 DO

            WHILE ra <= 40 DO

                INSERT INTO tabulka (REGAL,POLICE,RADA) VALUES(r,p,ra);
                SET ra = ra + 1;
            END WHILE;
            SET p = p + 1;
        END WHILE;
        SET r = r + 1;
    END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL proc();
```

[image]

EDIT: Now it generates only one loop:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL uses `WHILE DO`/`END WHILE` for it syntax.  So the stored procedure should look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc()
BEGIN
    DECLARE r int DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE p int DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE ra int DEFAULT 1;
    WHILE r <= 8 DO
        WHILE p <= 5 DO
            WHILE ra <= 40 DO
                INSERT INTO tabulka (REGAL,POLICE,RADA) VALUES(r,p,ra);
                SET ra = ra + 1;
            END WHILE;
            SET p = p + 1;
        END WHILE;
        SET r = r + 1;
    END WHILE;
END;
```

Here is a little [rextester](https://rextester.com/LSLHG15823).

Comment: Thanks, but now it only generates 40 rows with regal = 1, police = 1 and rada = 1 .... 40, but i want to generate regal 1-8 and rada 1-5

Comment: @adam . . . This is your code with the *syntax* errors fixed -- which is the question you asked.  If you have another question about *logic*, ask it as a new question.  That said, I suspect your problem is that you do not re-initialize the variable before restarting each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my mistake. I forgot to reset variables to 1 after inside loops was done. Thanks for help.